# Furnace fan will not turn off

Tags: thermostat

Our furnace fan runs continuously whether we have the switch set to ON or AUTOMATIC.  How do we get the furnace fan to shut off without having to go downstairs and turning switch off manually?

Comment: Well, that's what ON is for. Full time fan. If it's running in AUTO it's because some component in the system thinks it should be. Please revise to tell us more about said system. We're throwing darts in the dark otherwise.

Comment: I'll give the OP some time to [edit] more details (make/model of furnace & thermostat, set point temp, current room & outside temp, for example) before VtC for lack of detail.

Comment: What make and model is your furnace?  Have you tried checking to see if there's 24V between G and C at the furnace with the thermostat set to AUTO?  Can you post a wiring diagram for your system even?